# Failed to connect: Native host has exited

Tags: macos, file-permissions, chrome-native-messaging

I have been trying to communicate between Chrome Extension and App using Chrome Native Messaging API. I have throughly followed steps/instructions mentioned at [DeveloperChrome Website](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging). After downloading sample native messaging app from [NativeMessaging Examples](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging#examples), completed its setup by running `install_host.sh`. When I click on connect button in demo application, it fails with error:

```
Failed to connect: Native host has exited.
```

Besides this I ran Chrome instance from terminal in debugging mode by enabling its logs using command

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome 
--args --enable-logging --v=1
```

I found that something has been going wrong with permissions. Permissions of the file accessed are `Read&Write` for everyone. This issue is specifically related to MacOS as same example worked fine on Windows.
Here are the Chrome error logs:

> /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:
>   can't open file
>   '/Users/XXX/Desktop/host/native-messaging-example-host': [Errno 1]
>   Operation not permitted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit late here, but I just ran into this too. I managed to fix it by moving my host app into `/Applications`.

I suspect this is related to a Catalina permissions issue, though I wasn't able to find anything relevant in the "Security & Privacy" tab of System Preferences.

Comment: I already resolved this issue by granting access or moving host app into public directory. Anyways you pointed in the right direction. Thanks